# The type of column "" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this query

```
SELECT 
    MUESTRAS, POZOS, PRIORITY, NAME, VALUE
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         MUESTRAS, POZOS, PROJECTCODE, SAMPLETYPE,
         PRIORITY, CAST(VAR1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS VAR1, NUM1, NUM2 
     FROM 
         WS_LEYES_PTXT_PILAS_CALCULADAS) p
UNPIVOT
   (VALUE FOR NAME IN
      (VAR1,-- Varchar maybe Null
       NUM1,-- Float
       NUM2)-- Float
) AS unpvt;
```

I tried  converting all variables but I have the same error

Thanks! and rewards

Comment: Converting the variables is the answer, you must have made a mistake in the implementation.   Please post your attempt so that we can debug it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert all three columns to the same type:

```
SELECT MUESTRAS, POZOS, PRIORITY, NAME, VALUE
FROM (SELECT MUESTRAS, POZOS, PRIORITY,
             CAST(VAR1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS VAR1,
             CAST(NUM1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) as NUM1,
             CAST(NUM2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) as NUM2
      FROM WS_LEYES_PTXT_PILAS_CALCULADAS
     ) p
UNPIVOT
   (VALUE FOR NAME IN
      (VAR1,-- Varchar maybe Null
       NUM1,-- Float
       NUM2)-- Float
) AS unpvt;
```

You might want to use something like `str()` for more control over the format.